# Scripting update for User Mapping in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting, database-management

OK, First it's probably important to state that i'm a noob so please forgive me for any incorrect terminology or misconceptions.

My problem is this, I have a database that I run a restore on periodically and every time I run this restore it resets some user mappings that I have to go in and manually change.  I would like to script this change.

This is what I currently have

```
    USE profile

    Drop User [<UserName>]
    GO
    Create User [<UserName>] For LOGIN [<UserName>]
    GO
    exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'UserName'
    GO
```

This will work for accounts that are actually DataBase user Accounts. Although the account I am trying to fix/modify is actually a master account and is not linked to any database specifically.

Just in case my terminology is confusing i'll explain a little more. If you're looking at the object explorer in SQL Server. The account lives under 
ServerName>Security>Logins.

Not under ServerName>Database>DatabaseName>Security>Users.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear or more info is needed.

Comment: Are you talking about server roles?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677634.aspx - 'ALTER SERVER ROLE'

Comment: No i dont believe this is a server role.  If you're looking at sql server object explore navigate through the skill tree like so ServerName>Security>Logins. Located in the same tree as server roles but not a server role i don't believe.

Comment: Those are logins. `CREATE LOGIN`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx - Will create server-level logins.  Are you trying to add those to roles in the database?

Comment: So you think create logins should do it? I'm not necessarily trying to create a new login, but rather trying to modify an existing logins "properties" and change the user mapping to have db_owner selected via sql script.  I can do this through the ui, but need to write it out as a script to be efficient.